# How to show a input text field when a value is entered in input number type field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I m working on a form which have a field called amount field on which when a number is greater than 2000 than a pan card field is to be shown automatically as soon as the value is entered , I tried using javascript but i end up by this code below :

```js
    var amnt=document.getElementById("amount").value;
    var pandiv=document.getElementById("pancarddiv");
    function showPanfield(){
        if(amnt.value >= 2000){
            pandiv.style.display="block";
        }
        else{
            pandiv.style.display="none";
        }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Donation Form</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    div#pancarddiv {
        display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <label>Full Name*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="fname" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <label>Postal Address*</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="Address" name="address" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <label>Mobile No.*</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="mobileno" name="mobile" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <label>Email Id*</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <label>Amount (Rs.)*</label>
                    <input oninput="showPanfield()" type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group" id="pancarddiv">
                    <label>Pan Card No*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="panid" name="panid"/>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope if some one could help me to solve it that where i m lagging.

Comment: `var amnt=document.getElementById("amount").value;` gets the value once, at the beginning.  If you change the value in the input `amnt` doesn't change - move it inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you get the value of amount field once outside the function. You just need to change your `amnt` variable to be the amount element, not its value:

```js
    var amnt=document.getElementById("amount");
    var pandiv=document.getElementById("pancarddiv");
    function showPanfield(){
        if(amnt.value >= 2000){
            pandiv.style.display="block";
        }
        else{
            pandiv.style.display="none";
        }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Donation Form</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    div#pancarddiv {
        display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <label>Full Name*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="fname" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <label>Postal Address*</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="Address" name="address" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <label>Mobile No.*</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="mobileno" name="mobile" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <label>Email Id*</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <label>Amount (Rs.)*</label>
                    <input oninput="showPanfield()" type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group" id="pancarddiv">
                    <label>Pan Card No*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="panid" name="panid"/>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank u @Cuong Le Ngoc I got the mistake i was doing, can you tell me how can i make the pan card field as required once it  is shown after the value is greater than or equal to 2000 ?

Comment: You can target the pan input and set its required to true with `pandiv.querySelector("#panid").required = true;` and set it back to false when the amount is below 2000

Comment: thank you for giving me a basic idea @Cuong Le Ngoc ..... I did it using Javascript using by just adding the code in if condition (value greater or equal to 2000 : paninput.required=true; and false in else condition

Answer (score 0):

Two issues on this code

1. `document.getElementById("amount").value` returns a string so if you expect to get a number you should cast it as a number (e.g. using the [unary + operator](https://medium.com/@nikjohn/cast-to-number-in-javascript-using-the-unary-operator-f4ca67c792ce))
2. In the `if` statement you're trying a to still access to a not-existant `value` property of `amnt` variable which is a string and not an object

So to solve both the issues change the statement into

```
if (+amnt >= 2000) {
   ...
}
```

---

As a side note if you use an inline event handler you should not use parenthesys since you are assigning a function `oninput="showPanfield"`